# I have encountered problem in comparing to integer value in c. It couldn't be compared using '==' operator

Tags: c, struct

I have a encountered a problem for comparing integers in c. Normally two integers value can be checked by using '==' operator. But I can't figure out what is the problem with my code.

```
  struct customerdata
    {
      int accno;
      char name[40];
      int balance;

    }maxcust[200] = {
                02201002, "Ayush", 90,
                02201000, "Raman", 1000,
                01022001, "Hari", 50,
                02103405, "Kiran", 12
            };
    int checkacc(int acc, char names[])
       {
          int i;
          for(i = 0; i < 200; i++){
              if((strcmp(maxcust[i].name, names) == 0) &&
                               maxcust[i].accno == acc)
                  return 1;
            }

          return 0;
        }

        int main()
        {
           int acc, d, withdraw, amount;
           char checkname[40];
           printf("Enter acc number: ");
           scanf("%d", &acc);
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("Enter username: ");
           scanf("%s", checkname);
           fflush(stdin);
           d =checkacc(acc, checkname);
           if(d == 1)
             {
               printf("Username and acc matched... ");

             }
           else if (d == 0)
                 printf("Wrong acc number or name....");

            return 0;
        }
```

In this code checkacc function always returns 0 even if I enter same acc number and acc name as mentioned in struct.

(Sorry for my bad english.. Hope you will understand what I mean.)

Comment: What are the values of the mentioned variables when you debug your program? You can print them, hover over them, add them to your watch-window, ....

Comment: Code doesn't compile as-is, you have mismatched parentheses in `if(((strcmp(maxcust[i].name, names) == 0) && maxcust[i].accno == acc)`

Comment: Post the actual code. Also note that `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior. Also note that `02201002` gives an octal constant which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: My bad...i have mismatched parentheses during editing code. And thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your struct being initialised with octal (base-8) values, instead of base-10 values. When you `scanf`, you are reading in a base-10 value, so the equality comparison fails.

```
02201002, "Ayush", 90,
02201000, "Raman", 1000,
01022001, "Hari", 50,
02103405, "Kiran", 12
```

The `0` before a number indicates that it should be interpreted as a base-8 value instead of base-10. You can see your problem if you run the following small program, and pass it 02201002:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number = 02201002;
    printf("number: %d\n", number);

    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("number: %d\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

When executing the program, this gives:

```
$ ./octal_test
number: 590338
02201002
number: 2201002
```

Comment: For more info https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: Thank you. My code is working fine after these changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the leading zeroes in the account numbers. They're causing the compiler to interpret them as octal numbers rather than decimal. Try removing the leading zeroes.

```
struct customerdata
{
    int accno;
    char name[40];
    int balance;
} maxcust[200] = {
    2201002, "Ayush", 90,
    2201000, "Raman", 1000,
    1022001, "Hari", 50,
    2103405, "Kiran", 12
};
```